# Rails : how to get the instances having the same array of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a many to many relationship between 2 models, linked this way :

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :categoriesproducts
    has_many :categories, through: :categoriesproducts
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :categoriesproducts
    has_many :products, through: :categoriesproducts
    has_and_belongs_to_many(:categories,
     :join_table => "category_connections",
     :foreign_key => "category_a_id",
     :association_foreign_key => "category_b_id")
end

class Categoriesproduct < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :products
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Thus :

- A product can have many categories
- A category can have many products
- A category can have many categories

The user can query the DB selecting categories in a form. Say we have this in DB :

- Category 1 has [Category 3]
- Category 2 has [Category 3]
- Product A has [Category 1, Category 3]
- Product B has [Category 2, Category 3]

If users selects only Category 3 under Category 1 in the form I want to get only product A.

I have the following query :

```
Product.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: [1,3]})
```

Which gives me all products having either category 1 OR 3 = Product A and Product B.

How can I get the products that have categories exactly matching the array ? Eg only those having categories 1 AND 3, in the example = Product A

Comment: How about restruct DB schema? it seems that you can't get the desired result. For example, you add 'parent_category_id' column to `category` table.

Comment: You are right. I have let few weeks passed to check wether someone would know the clever activerecord query ... But in parallel I implemented a sub_category model that simplifies my life a lot. I was lazy at first but realized in the end few additional lines of code was the right solution. Thanks everyone for your time. I am not sure If I should delete the question or let it unsanswered ..

Comment: Cool! Sometimes simple code is good thing..

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like :

```
Product.includes(:categories).select { |p| p.category_ids == [1,3] }
```

Comment: This should work, but is very inefficient. This can be done in the database by double-joining `categories` but I'm not sure how to express this in activerecord.

Comment: Yes it works indeed, but I would like to keep an activerecord object, as this is chained with other queries